# object destroyed when request end

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Hi if I have the following codes in a controller, does the person object get destroy after the web page is served?

```
Person p = new Person();

for (int u =0 ...)
{
   p = new Person(); 
   p.save();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the object instances are all destroyed after the request is served. In your example, only the data in the database will exist across requests.

Read more about Grails controllers [in the official docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#controllers). See the section [*Controllers and Scopes*](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#controllersAndScopes) about the different scopes where you can store variables across requests.